# Angular 6 reactive form. How to build form for multiple languages

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am working on a CMS with Angular 6, I have a form to create a page with two languages or more depending on supported locales from the settings.
Firstly I am getting the supported locales from api and let's say the response has 2 locales (en - fr).
So for each language I want to build a tab inside the form with its own locale like en['title'], en['body'], fr['title'], fr['body'].
I tried to build the form like this:

```
let forms = [];
for(let lang of this.supportedLocales) {
    forms.push(this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      body: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }))
  }

  this.form = this.fb.group({
    template: ['default', [Validators.required]],
    is_home: [0],
    translatable: this.fb.array(forms)
  });
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div *ngFor="let lang of supportedLocales"
         class="tab-pane {{lang.locale === currentLang ? 'active' : ''}}"
         id="{{ 'tab_'+ lang.locale}}">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label [attr.for]="'title'+lang.locale">{{ translateField('page::pages.title') }}</label>
        <input formControlName="?" [attr.id]="'title'+lang.locale" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to define the formControlName for title field ?
I have tried to use FormArray but it causes a problem and the browser not responding!

What should I do or what is the best approach for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just use `.map` on `this.supportedLocales` and then generate `FormGroup`s using the `getFormGroupForLocale` method. It's `private` as it won't be used in your Template.

Now once the form is ready, first I'll bind the whole form to a `form` tag using `[formGroup]="form"`. After that, since my form has a `FormArray`, I'll first have to create a wrapping `div` for it. To this `div` I'll assign `formArrayName="translatable"` which will map this div to my `translatable` `FormArray` in the `form` `FormGroup`.

Inside this, I'll use `*ngFor="let group of localeFormArray; let i = index;"` to loop through all the `FormGroup`s in my `FormArray` and bind them to a wrapping `div` using `<div [formGroupName]="i">`. Notice how I'm using `formGroupName` as property binding syntax and assigning it the index `i` of the `FormGroup` in my `FormArray`

Finally inside each `input` tag of this `div`, I can then use `formControlName="title"` and `formControlName="body"` to bind to the `FormControl`s in each `FormGroup`s in the `FormArray`.

Here's how:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  template
  is_home
  translatable
  <label for="template">Template</label>
  <input type="text" id="template" formControlName="template">

  <br><br>

  <label for="is_home">Is Home</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="is_home" id="is_home">

  <br><br>

  <h1>translatable</h1>
  <div formArrayName="translatable">
    <div *ngFor="let group of localeFormArray; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label 
          [for]="'title'+supportedLocales[i].lang.locale">
          {{ translateField('page::pages.title') }}
        </label>
        <input 
          formControlName="title" 
          [id]="'title'+supportedLocales[i].lang.locale" 
          class="form-control">

        <br><br>

        <label 
          [for]="'title'+supportedLocales[i].lang.locale">
          {{ translateField('page::pages.title') }}
        </label>
        <input 
          formControlName="body" 
          [id]="'title'+supportedLocales[i].lang.locale" 
          class="form-control">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

And for the Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  supportedLocales = [
    { lang: { locale: 'en-US' } },
    { lang: { locale: 'en-FR' } },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      template: ['default', [Validators.required]],
      is_home: [0],
      translatable: this.fb.array(this.supportedLocales.map(locale => this.getFormGroupForLocale(locale)))
    });
  }

  private getFormGroupForLocale(language) {
    return this.fb.group({
      title: [language.lang.locale + 'Title', [Validators.required]],
      body: [language.lang.locale+'Body', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  ...

  get localeFormArray() {
    return (<FormArray>this.form.get('translatable')).controls;
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-locale-forms?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.